# Jquery:Mouseenter/Mouseleave with IE8 and Jquery 1.8

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter

I'm trying to add a border bottom in Jquery and this block of code does not work :

```
$('div#tableContent div.slot div.desc h2 a').on(function() {
    $(this).css("border-bottom","1px solid #FFF");
});

$('div#tableContent div.slot div.desc h2 a').mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css("border-bottom","none");
});
```

Is it because i'm using Jquery 1.8 and IE 8 ? 
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the event type in your first code block here:

```
 .on('mouseenter', function() {
 //---^^^^^^^^^^^----this event type is missing
```

---

Why bother to do this with js, you can achieve this with css:

```
div#tableContent div.slot div.desc h2 a:hover{
   border-bottom : 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: For an unknown reason it does not work with CSS that's the reason why i'm trying to do it through JS. It works properly with Chrome/Firefox but not IE

Comment: @ArnaudAd okay! then may be you have typo in the question as you have missed the event as i suggested but there could be anyother js error in the console, you can look for that also. Can you confirm that you don't have any error in the console of IE8.